# Retrieve copyright/license information from image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a web application which uses a large number of images(in different formats : jpg,png,gif..). The images were added over time and no information was stored about the URL from which they were downloaded or their respective licenses.

I am trying to write Java code to read the license information from the metadata of the images.So far, I have tried with javax.ImageIO and sanselan(now known as Apache Commons Imaging).

With ImageIO, I was able to get basic metadata about the image like its dimensions, bit depth, compression ratio but not licensing information. I was not able to use Sanselan with much success. It seems it uses a different class for each image type.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no licensing metadata attached to images. Companies use Tineye/Google Image Search and other services to track down their pictures and sue everything out of people. But that's it. Unless you write it into EXIF (which is not the purpose of EXIF) in JPG files, there is no way you could do this. (AS FAR AS I KNOW)

Comment: And the formats are different. PNG supports custom metadata. http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo Which you need to extract with hand (or a respective library). But if didn't ADD anything, there is nothing to extract.

Comment: Theoretically possible? Yes. Useful in practice? Probably not (unless you got most of images from news agencies or similar). Sounds like a lot of work for little gain. I'd use `exiftool` and `grep` for copyright/license on the command line and see if there will be any value in the approach, before actually implementing anything.

Comment: @Shiki, why is copyright not purpose of EXIF yet there being tags for both copyright and artist --- variable length ASCII strings --- `0x8298` and `0x013b` respectively?

Comment: @Vaaksiainen: Hmm I never ever saw anyone using such, in my entire life. But you are right, it exists (in JPEG, we still talking about).

Comment: ... and EXIF-TIFF. Even PNG takes it with the same tag, but stores in different form, however in such general that e.g. Photoshop recognizes it. Little usage sure, because you can remove it much easier than 'watermarks' on the image.